# How to run a VBA Macro by clicking Word 2010 Checkbox?

Tags: vba, checkbox, ms-word, word-2010

I want to run a macro when I click a checkbox in **Word 2010**.

**Note that I neither want the "Legacy Forms" checkbox nor the "ActiveX" ones!** They do only work in some "protected document mode" and look ugly, but I want the new ones which can be selected and unselected just when you write the document, and which look much nicer to me.

I know, with the legacy forms, you can directly insert a Macro when entering the form element and one for leaving it, and you can catch the event in VBA like

```
Sub CheckboxXY_Click()
```

But that does not work with the Word 2010 checkboxes, even when I give them a description and a tag name.

**Repeat**: these are the forms I want to use (just in case somebody would advise me to use the Legacy ones):

[image: Word 2010 checkbox]

And that's how they look like in the document (with mouse hover):

[image]

I cannot believe that I was the first one who tried this...

Comment: MS still haven't made it easy to program `Content Controls`. However, you should [check this out](http://gregmaxey.mvps.org/word_tip_pages/content_control_custom_events.html). This should be a good start.

Comment: maybe a loop?
Pseudocode:

while(!checkbox.checked)
{
  do nothing 
} 
do something

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you go to the Document in your VBA Project and select "ContentControlOnEnter"

You will have to specify which contentcontrol you want by using something like ContentControl.Title to specify which checkbox activates which part of your code as shown in the example below. (I also put in code to verify that the checkbox is checked in the example)

```
Private Sub Document_ContentControlOnEnter(ByVal ContentControl As ContentControl)
    If (ContentControl.Title = "Checkbox1" And ContentControl.Checked = True) Then
        MsgBox "YAAY", vbOKOnly, "Test1"
    End If
    If (ContentControl.Title = "Checkbox2" And ContentControl.Checked = True) Then
        MsgBox "BOOO", vbOKOnly, "Test2!"
    End If
End Sub
```